# Selenium and PHP

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium2, php

As I read on the net, Selenium tests should be written in the language of the App if this is possible. Our intranet-application is written in PHP. I was able to get Selenium working with PHPUnit but for me it looks like PHP is really uncommon. All books and most of the other stuff I found on the net are using Selenium together with Java.

So my questions are:

- Does it really make sense to use Selenium with PHP or do I have to
  learn Jave or C#?
- Where can I find the most information related to    Selenium together
  with PHP? I understand the object oriented model of    PHP but I'm
  not a very strong developer..
- Is there something better than Selenium to automated testing a PHP application (GUI tests)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes, it definetely makes sense to use it in a language you are comfortable with.
- PHPUnit has Selenium integration out of the box, did you look at the [introduction in the PHPUnit manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html)?
- Selenium has its quirks, but is widely used, so there is a lot of information about it available. There are other projects, though, like http://phantomjs.org/. If you are not comfortable with programming your tests in PHP, maybe you should consider using [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#), which has a GUI that helps you build your tests.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, this makes me more secure. I've to find the right solution for "my" company and I want to go in the right direction.